# Pandas convert mixed types to string

Tags: python, pandas, types

Given the following dataframe:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','D','D'], 
'mixed': [2016.0, 2017.0, 'sweatervest', 20, 209, 21]})
DF

    COL1    mixed
0   A       2016.0
1   B       2017.0
2   C       sweatervest
3   D       20
4   D       209 
5   D       21
```

I want to convert 'mixed' to an object such that all numbers are integers as strings and all strings remain, of course, strings.
The desired output is as follows:

```
    COL1    mixed
0   A       2016
1   B       2017
2   C       sweatervest
3   D       20
4   D       209 
5   D       21
```

Background info:

Originally, 'mixed' was part of a data frame taken from a CSV that mainly consisted of numbers, with some strings here and there. When I tried converting it to string, some numbers ended up with '.0' at the end.

Comment: Your original data have numbers with `.0` at the end. They're `float`s. Do you want to cast them to `int`s first?

Comment: I believe so. In the CSV file I'm using, there are no such decimals. They only got decimals after I converted them to strings via astype(str). So maybe I should begin from before that step if it would be easier. Otherwise, I'd like to first cast the number values as floats.

Comment: It looks like some are being read with decimals and others are not. So I think I need to: convert floats to ints then to strings, convert ints to strings, and keep strings as strings...but I don't know how.

Comment: The main reason I'm doing this is to be able to join data files and currently, it seems that one table has a key field that is of a different format than the other and I'm guessing that's why the join (pd.merge) is failing. I'm going to try stringed integer against scientific notation (see comment below) to see if it works.

Comment: @DanceParty. I've encountered a similar problem as you describe (csv file with mixed types). It helped to set `low_memory=False` as parameter for `read_csv()`. If I didn't do this, floating point (as strings) would be read even though decimal points weren't actually present in the csv file (only integer values mixed with other strings, but many (>10k) rows ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
DF['mixed']=DF.mixed.astype(object)
```

this results in:

```
DF['mixed']

0           2016
1           2017
2    sweatervest
3             20
4            209
5             21
Name: mixed, dtype: object
```

Comment: I just tried this. It left the decimal numbers as scientific notation.

Comment: And yet the join worked, so for my purposes, this solved the problem. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: By the way...what's the difference between using DF['mixed'] = DF.mixed.astype(object) and DF.mixed = DF.mixed.astype(object)?

Comment: no difference, although whether you can use the dot notation will depend on the label of the series. For example if you have white space in your field name.

Answer (score 3):

`df.mixed = df.mixed.apply(lambda elt: str(int(elt)) if isinstance(elt, float) else str(elt))`

This calls the `lambda elt: str(int(elt)) if isinstance(elt, float) else str(elt)` function over each element of the 'mixed' column.

Note: This assumes that all of your floats are convertible to integers, as you implied in your comments on your question.

Comment: I tried this but got this error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: If you want to figure out what is causing the issue, factor out the `lambda` into a separate function (defined with `def`) and add a try-except block around the expression with some print statements.

Answer (score 1):

This approach builds upon the answer by gbrener. It iterates over a dateframe looking for mixed dtype columns. For each such mixed column, it first replaces all `nan` values with `pd.NA`. It then safely converts its values to strings. It isusable in-place as **`unmix_dtypes(df)`**. It was tested with Pandas 1 under Python 3.8.

Note that this answer uses [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) which work only with Python 3.8 or newer. It can however trivially be modified to not use them.

```py
from typing import Union

import pandas as pd

def _to_str(val: Union[type(pd.NA), float, int, str]) -> Union[type(pd.NA), str]:
    """Return a string representation of the given integer, rounded float, or otherwise a string.

    `pd.NA` values are returned as is.

    It can be useful to call `df[col].fillna(value=pd.NA, inplace=True)` before calling this function.
    """
    if val is pd.NA:
        return val
    if isinstance(val, float) and (val % 1 == 0.0):
        return str(int(val))
    if isinstance(val, int):
        return str(val)
    assert isinstance(val, str)
    return val

def unmix_dtypes(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    """Convert mixed dtype columns in the given dataframe to strings.

    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826020/
    """
    for col in df.columns:
        if not (orig_dtype := pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df[col])).startswith("mixed"):
            continue
        df[col].fillna(value=pd.NA, inplace=True)
        df[col] = df[col].apply(_to_str)
        if (new_dtype := pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df[col])).startswith("mixed"):
            raise TypeError(f"Unable to convert {col} to a non-mixed dtype. Its previous dtype was {orig_dtype} and new dtype is {new_dtype}.")
```

**Caution**: One of the dangers of not specifying an explicit dtype, however, is that a column such as `["012", "0034", "4"]` can be read by `pd.read_csv` as an integer column, thereby irrecoverably losing the leading zeros. What's worse is that if dataframes are concatenated, such a loss of the leading zeros can happen inconsistently, leading to column values such as ["012", "12", "34", "0034"].